# rich:simpleTogglePanel neither calls action nor actionListener

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, action, actionlistener

I've implemented the following `rich:simpleTogglePanel`

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel 
      switchType="server"
      ationListener="swapPanelState" 
      action="swapPanelState2">
```

No matter which `switchType` I set - `server`, `ajax`, or `client` - neither the `` `action nor the ``actionListener` gets called. I've activated breakpoints at these methods and they never get invoked.

Here are the methods:

```
public Object swapPanelState2() {
    logger.info("swapPanelState");
    return null;
}

public void swapPanelState(ActionEvent event) {
    logger.info("swapPanelState");
}
```

The panel is nested inside a `h:form` tag. Other `actionListener`s are called without a problem. We're using RichFaces in the version 3.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write

```
actionListener="#{yourBean.swapPanelState}"
```

instead of

```
ationListener="swapPanelState"
```

Comment: Additionally to that, `switchType` has to be `server` or `ajax`.